# How to print some specific JTextFields and JLabels without Buttons and Scrollbars?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I know how to print JTable using this code:

```
try {   
      MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("We have to Pay, '" + txttotamnt.getText() + "'");
      MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page no {0} ");

      jTable2.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
    } 
      catch (Exception e) {
}
```

But i dont want to print a JTable, but other components like JLabels and JTextFields, while omitting all form controls like JButtons or JScrollbars.

Comment: by default `jTable2.print` printing only `JTable`s view

Comment: @mKorbel Tell me how to printing Other JTextFields & jLabels on Paper